# Cant get dropdown selected value with javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript

My drop down(populated with an `objectDataSource`):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat=server ID="ddlUserTypes" DataSourceID="odsUserTypes" AppendDataBoundItems=true DataTextField="UserType" DataValueField="Usertype">
<asp:ListItem Value="">-Please select one-</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Javascript function getting the selected value of the dropdown:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var notRegistered = false;
    var email = '';
    var userType = document.getElementById("ddlUserTypes");
    var pow = userType.options[userType.selectedIndex].value;
    function PreRegister() {debugger;
        if (notRegistered) {
            location.href = '/Register.aspx?pageid=<%= ConfigHelper.RegistrationPageId %>&Email=' + encodeURIComponent(email)+'&asd='+encodeURIComponent(pow);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

But this is not working `pow` just keeps on returning undefined? This may be because user type doesnt seem to get anything assigned to it as it stays as null? Does anybody know why this code is not working?

Comment: `ddlUserTypes` isn't the clientId.

Comment: What do you mean? Im a javascript newbie

Comment: Read my answer below.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but 'userType' was still null and 'pow' still undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this I hope it's working.

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlUserTypes");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

As gdoron mentioned, ASP.Net will make the HTML id of your dropdown something other than what you set as the ID parameter to your `<asp:DropDownList>`, which is why your JS isn't finding it.

What may be easiest is to assign a class to your dropdown, and then in your JS, target the element by class.

Comment: How can you target by class?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName, although you may want to look into using jQuery as it makes this kind of thing much more convenient.

Comment: Tried targeting by class but am still getting undefined

Comment: How did you specify the class on your DropDownList?

Answer (score 1):

```
var userType = documentgetElemebyById('<%= ddlUserTypes.ClientID %>');
```

[You should read this](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlClass" ...>
```

It will be transformed like

```html
<select class="ddlClass" ...>
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="value2">value2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

```
// use jQuery
var selected = $('.ddlClass').val();

// withour jQuery 
// method1
var selected1 = document.querySelector('.ddlClass option[selected="selected"]').value;
// method2
var selected2 = document.querySelector('.ddlClass option:checked').value;
```